# Angular material pre-built theme indigo-pink not taking effect

Tags: angular, angular-material

In my **styles.scss**

```
@import '~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css';
```

I have also tried to this in my **index.html**

```
<link href="node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Lastly I tried in my **angular.json** file

```
"styles": [
     "node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css"
]
```

[image]

Shouldn't this be pink?

Comment: No, it shouldn't be pink, it should be indigo which is what it looks like. The difference between `deeppurple-amber` and `indigo-pink` is very subtle. So `indigo-pink` is probably applied but you don't notice it. Try `pink-bluegrey`, this will very noticeably change your theme If this works, you know your themes are being applied.

Comment: @nash11 all i read is that i'm f***g blind hahahhaha you are right! it worked. feel free to post it as an answer

Comment: I wouldn't normally post it as an answer but it could probably help someone because the first time I tried this theme I had the same problem so don't worry it's not just you 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it shouldn't be pink, it should be indigo and your screenshot seems like it is being applied. The difference between `deeppurple-amber` and `indigo-pink` is very subtle. So `indigo-pink` is probably applied but it's not easy to tell the difference. Try `pink-bluegrey`, this will very noticeably change your theme. If this works, you know your themes are being applied.